# Does Intel MKL matrix product gemm work in-place?

Tags: matrix-multiplication, blas, intel-mkl

The BLAS gemm routine in the Intel MKL normally works with three matrices. It's like giving you `f(A, B, C) = alpha A * B + beta C` where alpha and beta are scaling factors.

But can one write `f(A, B, A)` with `alpha=1,beta=0` in order to simply get A = A * B? I mean the two `A`'s in `f(A, B, A)` are the same variable. (All square matrices here.)

Certainly, if we set a third variable `C=A`, `f(A, B, C)` works. But it will be much better without even making this copy `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not allowed. You either have to introduce a temporary buffer or find another way to do the job.